# Совершенный или несовершенный вид глагола, падеж и число дополнения

Tags: грамматика, дополнение

**За два года ни разу не (допускал просрочек(ки) / допустил просрочки) по сдаче налоговых деклараций и ни разу не (получал нарекания(ий) / получил нареканий) по их содержанию.**

Как будет грамматически верным? Вроде "ни разу" подразумевает совершённость действия и не предполагает продолжительности. Ещё с падежами и числами дополнений после отрицания проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

**За два года ни разу не допускал просрочек по сдаче налоговых деклараций и ни разу не получал нареканий  по их содержанию.**

**Здесь действие многократное**, сдача деклараций происходила несколько раз, отсюда множественное число и несовершенный вид глагола.

**В других случаях многократность может обозначаться или нет:**

Но Горький **ни разу не допустил** ни тени пользования своими хозяйскими правами, своим исключительным положением. [Н. Н. Суханов. Записки о революции / Книга 4 (1918-1921)]

За время учебы **ни разу не получал** из деревни писем...[Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

То жадностью, то бедностью томим, я писал эти штуки полгода, но **ни разу не получил денег.**.. [Валерий Попов. Очаровательное захолустье (2001)]

**Выбор Р.п. при усилении отрицания** http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=67

Comment: "В других случаях многократность может обозначаться или нет", — вы имеете в виду, что она может обозначаться или нет вне зависимости от того, имеет ли место такая многократность в действительности? Или просто, что есть такие и такие случаи?